# Converting a loadtxt column to a weekday: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file, and convert one column with a date, to a week number. I am getting below mentioned `TypeError`:

```
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime

def datestr2num(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%m-%Y").date().weekday()

dates, close = np.loadtxt(
    'data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(1,6), 
    converters={1: datestr2num}, unpack=True)

print("Dates =", dates)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

I tried to execute this program on Python 3.5.2 -Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: `loadtxt` does not return a tuple? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 4):

Converters are given the raw `bytes` value read from the file; you need to decode these to a string first if you want to parse them as a datetime value. ASCII should suffice as your input is simply a series of digits and dashes to form a date:

```
def datestr2num(s):
    s = s.decode('ascii')
    return datetime.strptime(s, "%d-%m-%Y").weekday()
```

Note: I removed the `.date()` call; the `datetime` object supports the [`datetime.weekday()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) directly.

Comment: Shouldn't a `csv` file be in plain text?

Comment: @ppasler: `numpy.loadtxt()` doesn't decode bytes when using converters.